# Rangechecks out of range access - C++

Tags: c++, windows

So I'm trying to inject a debug dll on my test process that just says "hello world" upon being successfully injected:

PS: I'm using C++/CLI to launch my C++ script from an interface.

**hello.dll**

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  reason,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        MessageBox(NULL, L"HELLO WORLD", L"INFO", NULL);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Below is the part of my code which takes this dll, allocates memory in the target process, writes the dll path to the latter allocated space. `LoadLibraryA` is then called to run the DLL from the path. However when I attach my vstudio debugger to the target process while injecting the DLL it crashes at the `LoadLibraryA` function with an error:

```
ntldll.dll rangechecks out of range access
```

PSS: the callstack just contains ntdll.dll functions

**Injection code**:

```
char* dll_path = "C:/some_path/hello.dll";
HANDLE h_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, debug_app_id);
HANDLE allocatedMemory = VirtualAllocEx(h_process, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(h_process, allocatedMemory, dll_path, strlen(dll_path) + 1, nullptr);
HANDLE h_thread = CreateRemoteThread(h_process, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, allocatedMemory, 0, 0);//crashes here
cout << "Success!" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Cleaning..." << endl;
CloseHandle(h_process);//dropping process handle
VirtualFreeEx(h_process, allocatedMemory, NULL, MEM_RELEASE);//release pointed to memory
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: when I try to allocate the memory I get `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `CreateRemoteThread` call, it needs to be `GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA")` as you are passing the address of `LoadLibraryA` in your own process' memory, while I believe the previous `GetProcAddress` call will get it from the `kernel32.dll` file.

Comment: I cannot recreate this error myself, man. Are you sure that is your original code?

Comment: Ah, this is from a github repo, I figure that would mean it should work. What process are you trying to inject into, that could be at issue

Comment: Right click on My Computer/This Computer, hit Properties, click on 'Advanced system settings', hit 'Settings' under 'Performance', hit 'Data Execution Prevention' and make sure the first circle is ticked, not the second

Comment: @Hjkl it is already ticked

Comment: You need to extend permissions for the allocation `VirtualAllocEx(h_process, nullptr, strlen(dll_path), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);`

Comment: @Hjkl oh yeah thanks, I'll try that